# How to use Mercurial's LargeFiles extension?

Tags: mercurial

I use Mercurial for game development, and I'm trying to use the LargeFiles extension included in Mercurial 2.0 to keep track of large binary assets. Unfortunately there isn't a whole lot of documentation on the extension, so I'm not sure how people are expected to use it.

For example, is there any way to safely clean out the .hg/largefiles directory? If I'm on the tip revision, and expect to always have internet access, then I don't need the old versions of largefiles cluttering up the repository, since that's the whole point of using the LargeFiles extension.

Also, how do I have more fine-grained control over where the largefile store is? I can only assume that it's created somewhere on the computer that ran `hg init`, but I have no idea about the details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I don't have any guidance on how to safely clean out the `.hg/largefiles` directory.

### Largefiles Store

The largefiles store seems to be stored, by default, at the one of following locations:

**Windows:** `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\largefiles`

**OSX:** `/Users/username/Library/Caches/largefiles`

**Linux:** (This is my best guess)

- `/home/username/largefiles`
- or `/home/username/.cache/largefiles`

**User Configured:**

This, however, can be changed in the global settings file using the `usercache` setting as follows:

```
[largefiles]
usercache = c:\path\to\largefiles\cache\
```

*Note: This is not documented yet.  This makes me wonder if it is subject to change.*

### Sources:

- [Largefiles Extension Documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LargefilesExtension)
- User cache paths - https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/41453d55b481/hgext/largefiles/lfutil.py (lines 84-103)
- Undocumented `largefiles.usercache` setting - https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3088

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't know where to start source-diving, so that's a great start for figuring out the subtle details. I suppose if there isn't any official documentation on the user cache yet, it might be a bit dangerous to make a bunch of changes with it.

Comment: John, I tried to put this 
([largefiles]
usercache=/mnt/driveb/mercurial-repo/largefiles)
in hgweb.cgi of the mercurial as well as the inside the .hg/hgrc of the repo on the server but i still get the same error. Am I doing something wrong? I'm using the standard version of mercurial 2.0, built from sources...

Comment: @Rok What was the error?  Did you also include [Extensions] largefiles=  to enable the extension?  My answer only describes where the files get stored and how to change that.  I would take a look at the documentation at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension if you are just getting started.

Comment: @JohnAllers: I got the extension enabled on client and the server. Commit goes well, push on the client throws this: 
abort: remotestore: could not put /path/.hg/largefiles/5ede... to remote store http://url/hg/testlargefiles
and on the server
[error] [client 192.168...] status = statusmessage(status.code, status.message)
[error] [client 192.168...] /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/hgweb/hgweb_mod.py:137: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
[Wed Nov 23 23:46:47 2011] [error] [client 192.168.150.233] return '0\\n%s\\n' % inst.message

Comment: @JohnAllers: I followed the official docs that you listed as well. Not sure what I could have missed. Is there a way to turn on hgweb.cgi debugging to give me more details?

Comment: @Rok Sorry, I'm not going to be much help with this issue. You may want to consider posting a separate SO question or try the Mercurial mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

I'm just posting this for anyone else coming into the thread from a search.

There's currently an issue using the largefiles extension in the mercurial python module when hosted via IIS. See [this post](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2593/cant-push-over-30mb-to-iis-via-https) if you're encountering issues pushing large changesets (or large files) to IIS via TortoiseHg.

The problem ultimlately turns out to be a bug in SSL processing introduced in Python 2.7.3 (probably explaining why there are so many unresolve posts of people looking for problems with Mercurial). Rolling back to Python 2.7.2 let me get a little further ahead (blocked at 30Mb pushes instead of 15Mb), but to properly solve the problem I had to install the [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx) utility to completely disable transfers over SSLv2.