# Managing binaries versions

Tags: version-control, binaries

I'm looking for tools and recommendations on how to manage binaries artifacts which together make up a release version.

The project looks like this:

```
+ Package-Version
|__ Component A-Version
|__ Component B-Version
|__ Component C-Version
```

More levels may exist, such that the components themselves are built from sub-components with their own versions.

Currently, we use an Excel with links to the binaries.
I hope to improve this by introducing some simple tools that may manage it better.
It should include some basics like: Searching for versions/sub-versions and locating where they are in the tree, WEB access to make it easily accessible and for it to have some interface so new binaries could be loaded using scripts.
Also, each item needs to have some info related to it, mainly a Release Note.

Note, this is an embedded C/C++ project if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual artifact repository recommended for binaries (managed in relation with a specific version of the code) is [**Nexus**](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).
For c++, you could also consider [**Nuget**](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) for managing those same dependencies.

In both cases, the idea is to store in the source control tool a file (pom.xml for Nexus for instance) which will specify the exact version of the binaries you need (or that you build and publish to that artifact repo)

By keeping the binaries *outside* the VCS (Version Control System), you make sure the VCS doesn't get too large (in disk space), and you allow IT Production team (in charge of release management) to access a different referential than the IT Dev team (clean separation of the two spaces).

Comment: Our Java developers use Nexus to import libraries and packages from the community. I was not clear if Nexus can be used for saving locally created artifacts. Do I understand correctly that Nexus can be used to store such local created components in a hierarchy?or is this hierarchy of components is managed through the XML file?

Comment: @EdwardH yes, you do understand it correctly: you can set up a *local* Nexus server which will mirror the public Nexus server (for the downloading part) while storing the artifacts you are producing (for the uploading part). You `pom.xml` can declare/manage both

Answer (score 1):

You can think and try Mercurial with [Largefiles extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) (precaution "... considered a feature of last resort" applied)

Some largefiles not-so-obvious details covered in

- [How to use Mercurial's LargeFiles extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197880/how-to-use-mercurials-largefiles-extension)
- [Largefiles Extension: Efficiently Handling of Large Binary Files](http://aragost.com/mercurial/largefiles/)

Comment: The artifacts are not so large, so using a VCS to manage them is applicable if we just look at the size angle. However, I found it difficult to use a VCS for this task because it is not transparent enough to all members of the organization (who need this version information). I prefer that all who need this information will access a web page and search for it, a VCS will usually need some client and search options or filtering inside a repo is not trivial.

Comment: @EdwardH -  Largefiles extension **does NOT store** artifacts in repository, read Wiki