# Is there a distributed version control system that handles big binaries well?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, binaryfiles

A few months ago we switched from Subversion to Git (mainly because Git is faster, more convenient for branching and generaly less pain). Only after some time we realized that Git is very ill-suited to projects with big binary files. As an example, Git hosting sites like GitHub or Bitbucket don’t like to support repo size much over 1 GB, because such repos swallow *a lot* of system resources on the server. Even on our desktop machines some repos with big binary artworks (like 100MB Photoshop files) take a lot of memory and CPU power. It seems like the consensus is that these big binary files don’t belong to the code repository, at least as far as Git goes.

Are there distributed version control systems that would handle big binaries just fine, with no extra memory or CPU requirements? I’m talking about file sizes in hundreds of MBs and repo sizes anywhere from 1 GB to 10 GBs.

Comment: Any possibility to split your repo and externalize your binaries to an artifact repo? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12509576/6309)

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial with largefiles extension have some glitches, but anyway work a **lot better** for your case